# 2sxc “Content” Module - Hiding advanced settings in menu

Tags: 2sxc

DNN Evoq Content 08.03.00 | 2sxc 8.8.0

We've encountered an issue in 2sxc 8.8.0 in which the module is providing full-fledge access to the instance settings [from the Module Action Menu] for a DNN role despite the fact that such a role has “Deny” access level to “Manage Settings” for the module instance [set by Portal Admin or Host].

Is there a workaround for this issue? Or can someone provide us direction on where in the module code we can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

On 2sxc you usually handle this at site level using the "2sxc Designers" role. You're probably looking for that. Read more about it here: https://2sxc.org/en/Docs/Feature/feature/3592

Comment: As you can see in the following screencast: [http://nimb.ws/2pE5R4](http://nimb.ws/2pE5R4) the user has been assigned the role "Webmaster" and is not a "2sxc Designers" but the module "Settings" is still available via the "Module Action Menu". Ideally we would like the module "Settings" to be disabled for the Webmaster role. Is this possible?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you actually mean the standard DNN settings (the ones you opened in the video)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The standard DNN module settings.

Comment: 2sxc does not influence those buttons at all. so if that's what you want to work on, best ask the question about any dnn module in the dnn area, not 2sxc